# calculating values for recursion functions

Tags: php, function, math, recursion

What to do with this? When writing the 4a() & 2a() should it be 4*a() or 4 * () without calling the a function?

[image: Function]

```
4a(2 - 1) - 2a(2 - 2) = 4a( 1 ) – 2a( 0 ) = 4 
4a(3 - 1) - 2a(3 - 2) = 4a( 2 ) – 2a( 1 ) = 6
4a(4 - 1) - 2a(4 - 2) = 4a( 3 ) – 2a( 2 ) = 8
```

Am I doing this correctly?

php code:

```
function a( $x ){
    print "a($x) = ";
    if( $x == 0 )   return 1;
    if( $x == 1 )   return 2;
//if( $x > 1 )  return 4*a( $x - 1)- 2*a( $x - 2); //this line A
//if( $x > 1 )  return 4*( $x - 1)- 2*( $x - 2);  //or this line B
}

for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++) print a($i) . "</br>";
```

To me it makes more sense to go with B, as it becomes useful for a function that simply doubles what ever is input.

Comment: Can you verify this for for a(2): 4*a(2-1) = 4*a(1) = 4*2 = 8, 2*a(2-2) = 2*a(0) = 2*1 = 2, 8-2 = 6.

Comment: Also, this is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question and not a programming question, not sure it is of the standards required for any of the specialized math sites in the network though.

Comment: Yep, wrong Stack Exchange, also way too broad. Flagging.

Comment: To put it on the maths site requires a special character in the password, however it will not accept what I try to put in and will not reveal what is classes as a special character, thus the reason I put it here!

Comment: To match the problem statement you have to go with choice  `A`.  This is a recursive function after all, which means it calls itself.  There is no call to `a()`  if you go with choice `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement describes a *recursive* function which by definition is a function that calls itself.  When called with `0` (i.e. `a(0)` so `k = 0`), the result is `1`.  When called with `1` (i.e. `a(1)` so `k = 1`), the result is `2`.  For values of `k` greater than or equal to `2`, you perform `4 * a(k-1) - 2 * a(k-2)`.  This is the *recursive* step where the function calls itself.  In this case it calls itself twice and then combines the answer.

Here it is in Ruby.  Your answers are incorrect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def a(k)
  return 2 if k == 1
  return 1 if k == 0
  return 4*a(k-1) - 2*a(k-2)
end

puts "a(2) = #{a(2)}"  // prints "a(2) = 6"
puts "a(3) = #{a(3)}"  // prints "a(3) = 20"
puts "a(4) = #{a(4)}"  // prints "a(4) = 68"
```

`a(0) == 1` and `a(1) == 2` are the base cases which allow the recursion to end.  All other values are computed recursively from values with smaller inputs.  Eventually everything ends up at `a(0)` or `a(1)` and then you just substitute in `1` or `2` respectively.

Here is how the computer solves `a(4)`:

```
a(4) = 4*a(4-1) - 2*a(4-2)
     = 4*a(3) - 2*a(2)
     = 4*(4*a(2) - 2*a(1)) - 2*a(2)
```

... and since `a(2) = (4*a(1) - 2*a(0))`

```
     = 4*(4*(4*a(1) - 2*a(0)) - 2*a(1)) - 2*(4*a(1) - 2*a(0))
     = 4*(4*(4* 2   - 2* 1)   - 2* 2  ) - 2*(4* 2   - 2* 1  )
     = 4*(4*( 8     -  2  )   -   4   ) - 2*(  8    -  2    )
     = 4*(4*      6           -   4   ) - 2*      6
     = 4*(   24               -   4   ) -    12
     = 4*           20                  -    12
     =       80                         -    12
     =                     68
```

That is the way the computer does it.  For humans it is easier to compute the values in increasing values of `k` because when we get to one we have already computed, we can just substitute the value:

```
a(0) = 1     // k = 0, so answer is 1
a(1) = 2     // k = 1, so answer is 2
a(2) = 4*a(1) - 2*a(0) = 4*2  - 2*1 = 8  - 2  = 6
a(3) = 4*a(2) - 2*a(1) = 4*6  - 2*2 = 24 - 4  = 20
a(4) = 4*a(3) - 2*a(2) = 4*20 - 2*6 = 80 - 12 = 68
```